Is there any way of filtering out header values of one data table based on header values in another in Spotfire?
Say I have a data table (DT1) whose contents are of the form :
Head1, Head2, Head3, Head4
Data....
Data....
Data....
And in another data table (DT2) whose contents are of the form :
A, A, B, A (Equal number of values as the header values in DT1)
I wanted to create a scatter plot visualization, with a custom property control with which I could choose any one of the header values in DT1 as the y-axis (and this I was able to do without too much trouble). Now I also want to add another property control where I can choose either 'A' or 'B', such that depending on which one is chosen, I only see the corresponding header values in the first property control (so if A is chosen, I should only be able to choose between Head1, Head2, Head4).
I've tried things like 'Filtering Related Table', looking into custom expressions to filter out values, etc. but the main issue I was facing was that each 'header' value in DT2 is being interpreted as a separate column.
I wasn't too sure what would be a proper approach of doing this, and all of the documentation I've gone through don't really deal with any cases like this. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated :)
